# can I use libicucore.dylib in ios8, is this a private library?

Tags: ios, iphone

1. Find some information about ICU for iOS, but it's several years ago, which said the that is private library, and can't use  when upload to AppStore? But if ICU can be used in iOS8? Is there any policy changed for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **libicucore.dylib** in your iOS app. For example: It's required library for [Google Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios).